# Just overwrote /etc/lib on Ubuntu 10.10. How can I best restore it?

Tags: ubuntu, restore

I've accidentally overwritten /etc/lib on Ubuntu 10.10 using sudo mv ( I was trying to put a folder in there, and I couldn't write using the GUI, and didn't want the libs sitting in my home directory).

The machine hasn't yet been powered off, and it's a WUBI installed version of ubuntu, if this makes a difference (dual boot with windows).

I have also pulled all the important documents off it, and on to another machine, so backup isn't a problem, and if I have to reinstall it doesn't matter too much, though I'd rather not.

How can I go about restoring the folder so I don't need to reinstall?

Comment: Did you just write to `/etc/lib` (in which case you didn't overwrite anything), or did you overwrite things in `/etc` (in which case you'll end up reinstalling unless you only lost a few pristine files), or to `/lib` (which is recoverable, but painfully)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a fool I am. There is no /etc/lib. So the question is really moot.

Answer (score 4):

You could boot a live CD version of 10.10 and copy the files from the live /etc/lib to your hard drive.

I'm running 10.4 LTS where /etc/lib is non-existent (at least on my installations) so if another program (not Ubuntu install) created /etc/lib then this obviously won't work.

Comment: I am running 10.10 and I don't have a /etc/lib/ directory either.